# Sprite not properly displaying

Tags: javascript, code.org

I'm using Code.org's game lab to make Tetris, and I have this sprite. https://ibb.co/zsT4LN6
You see the gray spots? They're like an empty background, but whenever a sprite touches the empty background, it stops moving. I want it to ignore the empty space. Is there a way to remove that or a block code to detect if a sprite touches a color

Comment: I'm guessing Game Lab is using the entire image itself as a sprite, disregarding the blue boxes. You would need to find a way to have the sprite fit only the content of the blocks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your *hitbox* is different then you want.

#### Option 1: graphical editing (design view)

In *GameLab* you can change this within the tab "Animation".
On the far right I see following elements:

- *Resize* as the top option (purple icon)
- *Crop the Sprite* as the bottom option (grey tiles)

#### Option 2: writing code (source view)

There are two approaches (commands on sprite) you'll want to try:

1. Use [`sprite.debug`](https://studio.code.org/docs/gamelab/debug/) to set the sprite's debug state to `true`. Then next time you run your code it will display a neon-green hitbox around the sprite.
2. You can change that **hitbox** through code using [`sprite.setCollider()`](https://studio.code.org/docs/gamelab/setCollider/).

Both commands are demonstrated in the following snipped:

```js
sprite.debug = true;
sprite.setCollider("rectangle", 0, 0, 20, 80, -45);
```

Comment: Great answer, even I as Code.org newbie could understand. Thus I upvoted and suggested an edit, to improve formatting (like usually done in Stackoverflow). If you don't like my edits, feel free to rollback ️